# Setting SHIFT+arrow keys to select text in emacs prelude

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

In emacs prelude I want SHIFT+arrow to select text. By default SHIFT+arrow is assigned to windmove. I've created a windmove.el file in my personal/preload folder with the following contents

```
(windmove-default-keybindings 's)
```

But with this both shift and command key are bound to windmove.

How can I bind only command key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bindings are set by windmoves `windmove-default-keybindings` function, you can undo what this function does with the following:

```lisp
(global-unset-key (vector (list 'shift 'left)))
(global-unset-key (vector (list 'shift 'right)))
(global-unset-key (vector (list 'shift 'up)))
(global-unset-key (vector (list 'shift 'down)))
```

Also, you'll need to ensure the variable `shift-selection-mode` is non-nil.

```
(setq shift-selection-mode t)
```

[Prelude disables arrow movement by default](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#warnings-on-arrow-navigation-in-editor-buffers), and for good reason. You are doing a great disservice to yourself by using arrow keys to select text. But if you really want to, this will allow you to.

```
(setq prelude-guru nil)
```

This should get shift-selection back up and running, but you'll need to find new keys to use for windmove.

Comment: Mmmmm... I'll take a look to the tutorial then ;). Thanks a lot both for the answer and the advice

Comment: @Jordon: How do I reset the windomove to other keys instead of disabling it ?
I know the general method, but is there any thing different as far as prelude setup is concerned ?

Comment: @Kayuntey: this is described on this site: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove, see "Terminals"

Comment: "You are doing a great disservice to yourself by using arrow keys to select text" The real use case here is `<a convenient modifier key>` + `<any navigation keys>` doing any navigation move + updating the selection. `<Shift>` + `<arrows>` is just the least important subset of the (optimal) special case of `Shift` being the mod. key. Then, the other key concept is _consistency_, to reduce cognitive burden. Dismissing this very effective usage model (engraved as a ubiquitous, basic reflex into the entire non-emacs world -- half the target audience of Prelude! :) ) sounds pretty darn dogmatic.